# Image src not changing accordingly

Tags: javascript, html

What i am trying to do is create a webpage with mercury's image attached to it('planet1.jpg')
and i created two button 'left' and 'right' that when clicked should change the img src to the planet right or left to it.
I use function leftClick() and rightClick() to calculate where it's position is and change src accordingly.
i couldn't find what i did wrong. Please help!

```js
// External JavaScript file
// that i linked using script tag
let pos = 0;

function leftClick() {
    if (pos > 0) {
        pos--;
        planetName();
    } else {
        continue;
    }
}

function rightClick() {
    if (pos < 7) {
        pos++;
        planetName();
    } else {
        continue;
    }
}

function planetName() {
    switch (pos) {
        case 0:
            document.getElementById("planetImage").src = "planet1.jpg";
            break;
        case 1:
            document.getElementById("planetImage").src = "planet2.jpg";
            break;
        case 2:
            document.getElementById("planetImage").src = "planet3.webp";
            break;
        case 3:
            document.getElementById("planetImage").src = "planet4.jpg";
            break;
        case 4:
            document.getElementById("planetImage").src = "planet5.jpg";
            break;
        case 5:
            document.getElementById("planetImage").src = "planet6.jpg";
            break;
        case 6:
            document.getElementById("planetImage").src = "planet7.jpg";
            break;
        case 7:
            document.getElementById("planetImage").src = "planet8.jpg";
            break;
    }
}
```

```html
<button onclick="leftClick()">LEFT</button>
<img src="planet1.jpg" id="planetImage" width="480" height="520" align="center">
<button onclick="rightClick()">RIGHT</button>
```

Comment: When this code is executed the browser's development console is telling you the error.

Comment: The continue statement breaks one iteration (in the loop), if a specified condition occurs, and continues with the next iteration in the loop. But you are using without a loop

Comment: Also, you can simplify the `planetName()` function to: `document.getElementById("planetImage").src = \`planet${pos+1}.jpg\`;`

Comment: Can you please elaborate the logic again?

Comment: @JohnnyMopp yes i would have done it, expect i had an image that was in .webp format. If everything was in .jpg i could have done it.

Comment: @JohnnyMopp plus i also wanted to adjust the size for each image 
separately.

Comment: Ok. I didn't notice the 3 was different.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like that `continue;` was causing an issue & once removed it works as expected:)

```js
// External JavaScript file
// that i linked using script tag



let pos = 0;

function leftClick() {
    if (pos > 0) {
        pos--;
        planetName();
    } 
}

function rightClick() {
    if (pos < 7) {
        pos++;
        planetName();
    }
}

function planetName() {
    switch (pos) {
        case 0:
            document.getElementById("planetImage").src = "https://metalinjection.net/wp-content/uploads/2019/04/davidhasselhoff.jpg";
            break;
        case 1:
            document.getElementById("planetImage").src = "https://www.al.com/resizer/x0sDT9S7MVuLoZdAckv4GYrEay8=/1280x0/smart/advancelocal-adapter-image-uploads.s3.amazonaws.com/image.al.com/home/bama-media/width2048/img/entertainment_impact/photo/22643993-large.jpg";
            break;
        case 2:
            document.getElementById("planetImage").src = "https://www.mensjournal.com/wp-content/uploads/2016/03/Hoff.jpg?quality=86&strip=all";
            break;
        default: 
        break;
    }
}
```

```html
<button onclick="leftClick()">LEFT</button>
<img src="https://static.independent.co.uk/s3fs-public/thumbnails/image/2016/03/03/11/Baywatch-The-Hoff.jpg?width=1200" id="planetImage" width="480" height="520" align="center">
<button onclick="rightClick()">RIGHT</button>
```

Comment: Yes, it works. But why, what was the reason continue was causing the issue? Just want to know.

Comment: @Sricharan [RTM](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/continue) _The continue statement terminates execution of the statements in the current iteration of the current or labeled **loop** , and continues execution of the loop with the next iteration._ You need to use it in a loop.